# Why am I getting the message IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'appium\\version.py'?

Tags: python, appium, robotframework

I am trying to run my android auomation using robotframework and appium. Appium seems to work fine when taking the screenshot of the device but when I try to run the automation code, im getting an error.

See Image below

[image: See Image below]

Comment: Please read [why you should not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). BTW error _"No such file or directory"_ happens when there is no such file or directory. Check the filename.

Answer (score 1):

Could be related to this [bug](https://github.com/appium/python-client/issues/333) in Appium-Python-Client version 0.37.

Try upgrading to 0.38 in which the issue has been fixed.